# how to make the webpage follow the size of the browser window and when resized, the layout does not get distorted?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I am currently working on a webpage and I have achieved fitting it in the whole browser window by using percentage(%) values in the width and height properties of my css. The problem now is that when I resize the window, everything gets scrambled and distorted (e.g labels,links, etc.) Is there a way to have a minimum height and width so as when the window is resized, there is a limit those properties to prevent the layout being distorted?

Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually answered the question yourself. You can use the CSS properties [`min-width`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/min-width) and [`min-height`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/min-height) to set minimum width and height, respectively, for a block level element like a container.

A better solution would be to use [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design), though, which will continually adjust itself as the window grows and shrinks.

Comment: hi there, thanks for the response. One question though, do i need to get rid of the percentage values on the width and height property?

Comment: hi there, in some cases this is not working. do you happen to know why? My pages are all using the same css. I dont know why this solution does not apply to my other pages. Is there a css property that should not be used when using min-width and min-height?

Comment: Just fixed widths would make max and min-height useless. Otherwise it's possible an element on the page is breaking things on you.

Comment: An element on a page? how could that be? The elements are enclosed in a div and the div has the min-width and min-height? so what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more. You may want to post this as a new question and show some code so we all can try to help

Answer (score 0):

Check out the css properties min-height:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/min-height

and min-width:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/min-width

You may also look into a simple css framework like StackLayout:

http://stacklayout.com/